# Iterate Over 2 Maps in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator

Doing commonCharacterCount from CodeSignal. Want to see how many Character are in common, of course.

### Here's an example:

For `s1 = "aabcc"` and `s2 = "adcaa"`, the output should be
`commonCharacterCount(s1, s2)` = 3.

### strings have 3 common characters - 2 "a"s and 1 "c".

Thougth about building an map with char count from each. Then I want to check every value in a map, and check both of them. To the answer I will add the minimum count of the char in both Maps.
For instance,
`s1 = "aabcc"` && `s2 = "adcaa"`, `mapS1['a'] = 2` && `mapS2['a'] = 3`, so `count += min(2,3)` = 2

That's my idea, but having some trouble with iterating both Maps as I mentioned.

First time using a map's value as a counting value. Can't really tell if that's the best way to increment a value in a map, so I guess I will need help with that as well.

Thank you in advance :)

```
static int res(String s1, String s2) {
                HashMap<Character, Integer> mapS1 = new HashMap<>();
                HashMap<Character, Integer> mapS2 = new HashMap<>();
                int count = 0;

                for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) 
                        mapS1.put(s1.charAt(i), mapS1.getOrDefault(s2.charAt(i), 0) + 1);

                for(int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) 
                        mapS1.put(s2.charAt(i), mapS2.getOrDefault(s2.charAt(i), 0) + 1);

                for(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : mapS1.entrySet()) {
                        int a = mapS1.get(entry.getKey());
                        int b = mapS2.get(entry.getKey());

                        if(a > 0 && b >= 0) count += Math.min(a, b);
                } 

                return count;
}
```

CORRECTED AND WORKING VERSION: Thank you everyone!

````
static int res(String s1, String s2) {
                HashMap<Character, Integer> mapS1 = new HashMap<>();
                HashMap<Character, Integer> mapS2 = new HashMap<>();
                int count = 0;

                for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
                        mapS1.put(s1.charAt(i), mapS1.getOrDefault(s1.charAt(i), 0) + 1);
                for(int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++)
                        mapS2.put(s2.charAt(i), mapS2.getOrDefault(s2.charAt(i), 0) + 1);

                for(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : mapS1.entrySet()) {
                        int a = mapS1.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), 0);
                        int b = mapS2.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), 0);
                        System.out.println(a + " " + b);
                        count += Math.min(a, b);
                }

                return count;
        }
```
````

Comment: Your approach looks okish to me. What is the issue you're facing exactly?

Comment: Should have been more informative about my issue, sorry about that.
Getting a NullPointerException in my int b initialization

Comment: Try using `getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), 0)` in place of the `get()`. There isn't any value for a given key, it returns a null and then tries to assign it to an int variable, which isn't possible and thus a NPE.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much, exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code. First, "less important" is the copy-paste error. In the second loop you're adding elements to the `mapS1` again, I believe it was meant to be `mapS2`.

As you've mentioned in the comment, the main problem is the NullPointerException you're getting in this line:

```
int b = mapS2.get(entry.getKey());
```

This is caused by the fact that if there isn't any value for a given key it returns `null`. Then that `null` is supposed to be assigned to `b` which is an `int`. `int` variables doesn't accept null values and thus throws NPE. The easiest solution is to return a default value if there isn't any mapping present. You can do it like this:

```
int b = mapS2.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), 0);
```

Comment: That's exactaly all the problems that I was having, so will mark it as the most complete answer :). Thank you so much! Everything working as it should rn :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error here:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) 
        mapS1.put(...); //<------ should be mapS2.put?
```

Comment: `s2.charAt(i)` in the first loop also isn't right i guess and should be `s1` instead. There is quite a mixup in the loops with s1 and s2 and mapS1/mapS2.

Comment: Yup, I made a lot of error there. Problem with copy-pasting and being distracted :p
Gonna edit the correct version, thank you!